# Confusing number format exceptions

Tags: java, exception, number-formatting

I'm getting a whole slew of exceptions that seem to stem from my parse double since their info is: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
another likely suspect is

```
account1.withdrawl(checkingBal, changeValue) ;
```

which is convinced it's an unreported exception despite my try catch block in the method being called:

```
public double withdrawl(double currentBal, double withdrawlAmount) throws InsufficientFunds{
    int i =0 ;
    double overDraw = 0 ;
    try{
    //verifies that input was numeric and evenly divisible by 20
  if(withdrawlAmount % 20 == 0){
    if(i>4){
        if(currentBal>1.5){
        currentBal = currentBal-1.5 ;
        }else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Insufficient funds");
        overDraw = currentBal-1.5 ;
        throw new InsufficientFunds(overDraw); 
        }
    }
    //stops withdrawl for insufficient funds
    if(currentBal<withdrawlAmount) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Insufficient funds");
        overDraw = currentBal-withdrawlAmount ;
        throw new InsufficientFunds(overDraw);
    }else {
        currentBal=currentBal-withdrawlAmount ;
    }
    i++ ;
  }else {
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter a withdarl amount that is divisible by 20");
  }
    }catch (InsufficientFunds ex){
        ex.getAmount();
    }
  return currentBal ;
 }




public class ATM extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
JButton withdraw, deposit, transfer, balance ;
JTextField input ;
boolean checkingActive = true ;
public double checkingBal = 0 ;
public double savingsBal = 0 ;
```

Main class:

```
ATM(){
withdraw = new JButton ("Withdraw") ;
deposit = new JButton ("Deposit") ;
transfer = new JButton ("Transfer") ;
balance = new JButton ("Balance") ;
input = new JTextField (12) ;
input.setText("0") ;
input.setEditable(true) ;

JRadioButton checking = new JRadioButton("Checking", true) ;;
JRadioButton savings = new JRadioButton("Savings") ;
this.add(checking);
this.add(savings);
ButtonGroup acctSelector = new ButtonGroup();
acctSelector.add(checking);
acctSelector.add(savings);


add(withdraw);
add(deposit);
add(transfer);
add(balance);
add(input);

//assigns buttons to logic gorup
ButtonGroup accountChoice = new ButtonGroup();
accountChoice.add(checking) ;
accountChoice.add(savings) ;

input = new JTextField(6) ;

//assigns listeners to buttons
withdraw.addActionListener(this) ;
deposit.addActionListener(this) ;
transfer.addActionListener(this) ;
balance.addActionListener(this) ;

setSize(500,400) ;
setLayout(new FlowLayout()) ;
setTitle("MoneyBank ATM") ;
}

//acceses account changes
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
 double changeValue = Double.parseDouble(input.getText().trim());
 Account account1 = new Account() ;
 if(checkingActive==true){
    if(e.getSource()== withdraw){
      account1.withdrawl(checkingBal, changeValue) ;
    } else if(e.getSource()== deposit) {
       account1.deposit(checkingBal, changeValue) ;
    } else if(e.getSource()== transfer){
       account1.transfer(checkingBal, changeValue) ;
    } else {
       account1.balance(checkingBal) ;
    }
 } else {
    if(e.getSource()== withdraw){
      account1.withdrawl(savingsBal, changeValue) ;
    } else if(e.getSource()== deposit) {
       account1.deposit(savingsBal, changeValue) ;
    } else if(e.getSource()== transfer){
       account1.transfer(savingsBal, changeValue) ;
    } else {
       account1.balance(savingsBal) ;  
    }
 }
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Current balances are: \n Savings: " + savingsBal + "\n Checking: "+ checkingBal);
}

//constructs atm object/GUI
public static void main(String[] args){
ATM account=new ATM();
account.setVisible(true);
account.setLocation(200,200);
account.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public boolean pickAccount(boolean k) {
   checkingActive = k ;
   return checkingActive ;
}

}
```

Comment: When I put try - catches around the withdawl code it didn't change anything so my best guess is still the parse. but I have a default value so I'm not sure why it's having trouble

Comment: Realized while looking around that I never set up a proper action command for my radio buttons so I'll see if fixing that does anything. EDIT: it did not but at least I fixed that part of my problem

Comment: better to have a data validation before you do this Double.parseDouble(input.getText().trim())

Comment: A fair point but I'm entering what seem to be acceptable values and it still fires off the exceptions

Comment: try print out the value of the input before invoke withdrawl(), the exception doesn't seem to come from inside withdrawl. Does exception itself show which line of code throwing the error?

Comment: Personally, I would have to say that `input.getText()` is not supplying what you think it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating 2 different JTextField instances for the variable input.

The first:

```
input = new JTextField(12);
input.setText("0");
input.setEditable(true);
```

The second:

```
input = new JTextField(6);
```

So, when you write a number in the field and send the value to process, what you are receiving is an empty value "". And the end your application tries to generate a Double from that empty causing:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
```

You can comment or delete the second instance and your application will work.